# Fitting lognormal distribution using percentile matching - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, curve-fitting, distribution

I have a very limited cumulative probability information as shown below:

```
x1=6      F(x1)=0
x2=7.25   F(x2)=0.1
x3=8      F(x3)=0.35
x4=9.5    F(x4)=1
```

I want to fit this data using cumulative log-normal distribution curve. I know that there is a method called percentile matching for estimating the parameter from this kind of information. But we usually use only 2 data, since there are only 2 unknown parameters.

But here, I have to accommodate the upper and lower thresholds. Is there any way to do this using MATLAB?

Any reference about estimating lognormal distribution parameters using percentiles information would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take the log, then fit a normal distribution. Fitting a normal distribution is just computing the mean and std. dev. But 4 points? That’s going to be a bad fit. You can also fit a normal using percentiles, but you’ll need many more points than this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo your comments are unfortunately off the mark. OP doesn't have a sample from the distribution in question, so the sample mean and s.d. aren't applicable. Also, whether or not 4 values are good or bad isn't immediately relevant; OP has been given 4 values, and the question is how to best make use of them.

Comment: Aeroplane, to solve this in Matlab, my advice is to define a function which calculates the log-likelihood as a function of the free parameters (mu, sigma, and offset), and then apply one of Matlab's numerical optimization algorithms. About the log-likelihood, take a look at my answer for this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11176 But see also the answer from Matthias Greiner for this other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022 Yet another question might provide some insights: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104810

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I have updated my question. Maybe my previous question was not clear enough. I don't have a sample here. I only have 4 percentile data.